# Why does Codeception suddenly ignore my code?

Tags: laravel, testing, functional-testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

My app is created with the Laravel framework and is tested with Codeception.

Without changing the `codeception.yml` or the `.ymls` in any test suite, the coverage of codeception suddenly ignores part of my code. As if the lines are suddenly not recognised as code at all. How can this happen?

**My codeception.yml**

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
coverage:
    enabled: true
    include:
        - app\Http\Controllers\*
        - app\Http\Traits\*
        - public\js\*
```

**My acceptance.suite.yml**

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunProcess:
            0: java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
            sleep: 5
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver:
        url: http://localhost:8000
        browser: chrome
    - Db:
        dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=string_translations'
        user: 'root'
        password:
        dump: tests/_data/empty.sql
        populate: true # load dump before all tests
```

**My functional.suite.yml**

```
actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
            cleanup: true
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=string_translations_test'
            user: 'root'
            password:
            dump: tests/_data/test_dump.sql
            cleanup: true # reload dump between tests
            populate: true # load dump before all tests
```

Comment: Needs more supporting information - my gut is that you have a subtle syntax error. What result do you get doing `codecept run -f -vvv`?

Comment: What do you mean by ignoring part of your code? Could you elaborate a bit more.